# Can't get rid of gnome classic panel

Tags: gnome

I've changed my ubuntu desktop environment from unity to gnome. It works almost fine but I don't like gnome classic panel (attached)[classic panel on default user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUs6D.jpg). The weird thing here is that after creating another new user, gnome layout is different (exactly as I like [non classic gnome on new user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvGPb.jpg)). I would like to get rid of gnome classic. Is there any way to do this? I've tried to find this configuration in tweak tool with no success.

Data : Ubuntu 16, gnome3

Answer (score 0):

Remove those panel first.

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove gnome-panel gnome-panel-data gnome-session-flashback
```

Then, Try resetting gnome settings using this command

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/
```

This should reset the session and settings.

Comment: Thanks Anwar, really apreciate your help. But I'm afraid  I've not explained properly. What,  I need is to  change the gnome panel appearance. I don't like the gnome classic panel so I would like to remove it. How can I do it?

Comment: @JGomez oh! remove `gnome-panel` and `gnome-panel-data`

Comment: @JGomez tried this solution?

Comment: Hmmm yes. I'm afraid it didn't work actually...